# Why does this generic TypeScript function not work, when an equivalent non-generic version works fine?

Tags: typescript

I have two functions, `foo1` and `foo2`, which are almost identical except that the latter is generic.

```js
type MyType = { a: number }

type PartialWithBar<T> = Partial<T> & { bar: boolean }

export const foo1 = (obj: MyType) => {
  const result: PartialWithBar<MyType> = { bar: false }
  Object.assign(result, obj)
  return result
}

export const foo2 = <T extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(obj: T) => {
  const result: PartialWithBar<T> = { bar: false }
  Object.assign(result, obj)
  return result
}
```

`foo1` doesn't give any errors, but in `foo2` I get the following error:

```
Type '{ bar: false; }' is not assignable to type 'PartialWithBar<T>'.
  Type '{ bar: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.ts(2322)
```

Why am I getting this error? I want `result` to have the property `bar` which should be a boolean, and I want it to optionally have the properties of `T`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I know that I could just use a type assertion (`const result = { bar: false } as PartialWithBar<T>`), but I don't want to do that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a value to be assignable to the intersection type `Partial<T> & {bar: boolean}`, it must be assignable to *both* types, because intersection corresponds with logical "and". The value `{bar: false}` is assignable to `{bar: boolean}` but it is not necessarily assignable to `Partial<T>`.

The latter depends on what `T` is. In particular, when `T = {bar: number}`, the type `PartialWithBar<T>` is actually `never`:

```
type Example = PartialWithBar<{bar: number}>
// type Example = never
```

So Typescript is correct: your result is not necessarily assignable to this type, because `T` might be something that makes it not assignable.

Fortunately there is a nice solution here that avoids a type assertion: `Object.assign` itself returns an intersection type, and Typescript is able to know that `T` is assignable to `Partial<T>`.

```
export const foo2 = <T extends object>(obj: T): PartialWithBar<T> => {
  return Object.assign({bar: false}, obj);
}
```

However, note that while `Object.assign`'s return type is convenient, it isn't sound in general, for the same reason as discussed above. For more safety, you can also eliminate the property `bar` from the type `T` in case it is present. Note that the above, like your original code, will keep the `bar` property from `obj` if it has one, so the correct type is like this:

```
type PartialWithBar<T> = Partial<T> & Omit<{bar: boolean}, keyof T>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwOrOACwEKIA8AKgHxQC8siK6J5AZFAPIC22hA3gEaIBcUbgHshaCHAB2AXwA0UANYQQQgGZQyAKA0QAHmCFIoAYyESAzsCgqRAJkpQSUXcAgSAJmahDuAKwhHgUgAKbx8BYgBKAXgkVExsfCIySnJODSgoBAhgAFcECRZff2AAOjgzM2QAcwkgnn4rdDMIWS9fCI0pDSA)

If instead you prefer to overwrite the `bar` property when it is present, you should write this instead:

```
type PartialWithBar<T> = Partial<Omit<T, 'bar'>> & { bar: boolean }

export const foo2 = <T extends object>(obj: T): PartialWithBar<T> => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj, {bar: false})
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwOrOACwEKIA8AKgHxQC8siK6hA8gLbYkA0UA5AEaIenkAyKAG8oPBAC4xAe2loIcAHZQAvgCg1EAB5hpSKAGNpigM7AoAM1kAmSlBJRtwCIoAmJqNK4ArCAeCkABRe3lLEAJRS8EiomNj4RGSU5MJqUFAIEMAArgjK9D5+wAB0cCYmyADmioHCKuwh7MLiUhboJhAq4WrqQA)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! I guess I might have made my example too simplified, because I don't necessarily want everything in `obj` to end up in `result`, I conditionally add some of the properties with potentially modified values. Is there a solution for this case?

Comment: In that case, I suggest building the object with just the properties you want from `T`, and then using this approach to merge in the additional properties afterwards.

Comment: I don't want to keep all of the additional properties though - I definitely want `bar`, and I may or may not want to add the other properties of `T`, which I had thought `Partial<T> & { bar: boolean }` would permit (although of course the error is telling me otherwise!)

Comment: Yes, so build an object with the properties you do want, and then use `Object.assign` to add `bar` to that.

Answer (score 0):

To add another answer to my question:

```js
export const foo2 = <T extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(obj: T) => {
  const part: Partial<T> = {};
  const result: PartialWithBar<T> = { ...part, bar: false };
  // Optionally do stuff e.g. Object.assign(result, obj)
  return result;
};
```

Given that this answer works too, I'm still not convinced that there isn't a bug in TypeScript that is causing the error I initially posted.

Comment: This isn't indicative of a bug, it's just that Typescript's types for object spreading are as unsound as `Object.assign` is.